# "Last changed" option for sorting tags

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-wiki, tags-page

We have "Popular", "Name", "New" sorting options for the [Tags page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags).

[image]

Would be great to add additional option "Last changed" to see tags, whose tag wiki (or tag wiki excerpt) was edited, sorted by editing date.